# Extracting transactional data from PDF row wise by using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to extract the transactional data from the PDF as a simple program using Python 3. What I am seeing is the output is returning as garbage text from page 1. This is happening to the specific bank statement pdf whereas other PDF works fine.

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('st1.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

6
   ÉŁ@äKâKñ`øðð`õòô`óøøðÅ¢Š†IŒﬁñ`øøø`ôôö`óóðøããèñ`øðð`ùõõ`øðöð×†¨@‡¨@Š‹ŒŁ–
   ñ`øðð`ôóö`÷ùõøÖ¤£¢›—–@äKâK@…†ﬁﬁ@…Œﬁﬁ–…£ñ`óðò`õùô`øòðð

Not sure if there is any similar issues other faced? or any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe it is stored as an image? Encoding problems? (just random guesses)

Comment: Does it work for other pages in this pdf?

Comment: @Anton vBR This entire file is not image file though the logo is image which i can ignore as I want to only extract text. Joe - All pages are giving same issue. Yesterday I tried with online conversion website to convert to xls which was able to convert so wondering what's the issue here!!